# python-is-python-2 package... something new?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, apt, ubuntu-20.04

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Ubuntu 20.04 (dev branch) and I have noticed that `sudo apt install python` installs `python-is-python-2` instead of `python2` (from Ubuntu 18.04) or `python-minimal` (from Ubuntu 20.04 dev).

Is this something new? Is this package different in any way with respect to the other two? As of now, the installation is complete and I notice that `python2` opens up Python 2.7 in the terminal.

Comment: You should really just stop using Python 2, it's EOL.

Comment: I think I have to, since I want to build node.js

Comment: Why? You can get the Linux binary tarball for any version of Node from nodejs.org.

Comment: @AKX Cool, I'll check it out

Comment: Besides, I'd imagine Ubuntu 20.04 has a recent version of Node in its default repos?

Comment: @AKX yeah, it was not that clear from BUILDING.md but I later realized that I can just do `sudo apt install nodejs` and did that. Thanks!

Comment: @AKX we don't really have a choice if it is legacy code and not ours, that's the problem with deprecation without a compatiibilty wrapper.

Answer (score 14):

This no longer happens in ubuntu 20.04. The `python-is-python2` package no longer exists (but there is `python-is-python3` which does the same thing but makes
the `python` command call `python3`).

If you still need `python2` to be the default for the python command you can do something like:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

This can be important if you are using something like `repo` which doesn't support python3 (and maybe never will). [See here](https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss/c/MVOoA4WGYig?pli=1).

Comment: As of ubuntu 22.04, the python-is-python2 package still exists and can fix the problem easily.

Comment: @Cris you probably would not want it anymore as it breaks/conflicts with `dh-python`, a critibal tool for dpkg to pack up and build python3 related packages. Google `dh-python breaks python` would give you some ideas. I don't see why `dh-python` is not fixed; probaby the author does not want to.

Comment: I am trying really bad to install medeley desktop via dpkg and it still asks for `python`. I tried the symbolic link and nothing. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: @EduardoReis you should open a new question, maybe on `Ask Ubuntu`.

Comment: As of April 2023, python-is-python2 is no longer there on 22.04